# My openlitespeed virtual host external app does not run as required user

Tags: virtualhost

I'm trying to setup OpenLiteSpeed, and I want PHP to run as a certain user and a certain group in a certain virtual host. I've turned the entire knowledge base upside down, especially [this section](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/change-php-settings-by-vhost-and-user/) obviously.

But, whatever I do, the PHP socket that is created is owned by the default `nobody` and `nogroup`, and the documentroot is unreachable (403) as long as it's owned by a user/group combination where `nobody` is *not* in the group.

So far, I've:

- Set the `External App Set UID Mode` to `DocRoot UID` (as per documentation)
- Set the user and group explicitly in `suEXEC User` and `suEXEC Group` in the **Basic -> Security** section of the Virtualhost
- Created a dedicated External handler for the Virtual host, where I also set the desired user/group combo
- Even set the desired user/group combo in the External App handler on the server level.

But nothing changes the default `nobody`/`nogroup` behavior.

Comment: OpenLiteSpeed process runs as nobody(in nogroup group) user, so set 750 to the document root folder and owned by the [virtual host user]:[nogroup], so the web server has permission to access it.